# Issue reading pre-compiled shader file to ID3DBlob

Tags: c++, pointers, directx

I am having some issue reading pre-compiled shader file and it is probably very newbie mistake I am doing here.

I have a ReadShaderFileToBLob function that is supposed to load the cso file:

```
void cShader::ReadShaderFileToBLob(std::string File, ID3DBlob* fileData)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(File.begin(), File.end());
    LPCWSTR sw = stemp.c_str();

   hr = D3DReadFileToBlob(sw, &fileData);
}
```

and I am calling that function from LoadVertexShader function:

```
void cShader::LoadVertexShader(std::string vertexShaderFileName)
{
     // class member that store file name
     m_vertexShaderFile = vertexShaderFileName;

     HRESULT hr = S_OK;

     ReadShaderFileToBLob(m_vertexShaderFile, vertexShaderBytecode);

     hr = wwRenderManager::Get().GetDirect3DDevice()->CreateVertexShader(
                          vertexShaderBytecode->GetBufferPointer(),
                          vertexShaderBytecode->GetBufferSize(),
                          nullptr,
                          &m_vertexShader);

   if (FAILED(hr))
   {
       vertexShaderBytecode->Release();
       wwASSERT(wwFALSE, "Failed to create vertex shader.");
   }
}
```

vertexShaderBytecode is a ID3DBlob pointer, which is a private member in the class. During the execution, the

```
 hr = D3DReadFileToBlob(sw, &fileData);
```

call is returning success.
however, in the LoadVertexShader function, vertexShaderBytecode is still null.

What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: this is c++, not c.  Please remove the 'c' tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'fileData' argument for ReadShaderFileToBLob should be ID3D11Blob*&.

D3DReadFileToBlob will set your 'fileData' argument to a valid value, but this is just an argument to the function which falls out of scope at the end of the function in the same way an integer would.